# Subquery as Dataset

Tags: sql

I'm having problems with a subquery. The subquery works by itself; I need the logic to produce the data set I need. But when I try to use it as a data set, I get the error below. I can do this with a join, obviously, but I need this particular solution to employ a subquery approach. I'm using SQLServer 2008 R2.

```
select BK.book_id
from bkinfo.books BK
where BK.book_id in
(
  **select OD.book_id, sum(OD.quantity) as TotSales** see error below
  from  
    bkorders.order_details OD
  group by
    OD.book_id
  having
    sum(OD.quantity) > 500  
)
```

error msg:
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Answer (score 0):

the IN clause requires a query that returns only one column. Try this, 2008 supports CTEs:

```
;with cte as 
(
    select 
        OD.book_id, 
        sum(OD.quantity) as TotSales
    from  bkorders.order_details OD
    group by OD.book_id
    having sum(OD.quantity) > 500
)
select c.book_id, c.TotSales
from cte c
join bkinfo.books bk on bk.book_id = c.book_id
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I started with a CTE but couldn't make it work. Now I see the problem. Thank you very much. --Tim